# Treeview on JSP pages

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

What's the best way to render a treeview on JSP? I need it for site naviation.

I'm using Spring MVC and jQuery for the presentation layer. I'm not planning to support AJAX at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: Really, tree view navigation?  I haven't seen that on many sites any time recently.

Comment: It's for administrators only. It's more like Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Prize Tags](http://jenkov.com/prizetags/index.html). I used it a few years ago in a Spring MVC project.